# ABIs [armeabi, mips] are not supported for platform android NDK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am using JNI code in my project with `abiFilters` like below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.intel.hellojni"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

it's working fine in one system but after moving a code to other system,it show below error for import,i have checked with new created project it shoes the same error

```
ABIs [armeabi, mips] are not supported for platform. Supported ABIs are [armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64].

Build command failed.
Error while executing process F:\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HC:\Users\Intel\Downloads\TestJNI\app -BC:\Users\Intel\Downloads\TestJNI\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-15 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Intel\Downloads\TestJNI\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DANDROID_NDK=F:\sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=F:\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=F:\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja}
 (include)   CMakeLists.txt 
Open File
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

if I remove `armeabi` and `mips` like below then it's working

```
ndk {
       abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
}
```

I have already installed CMake and NDK for android studio.

Comment: That's intentional. From the NDK r17 release notes: _"Support for ARMv5 (armeabi), MIPS, and MIPS64 has been removed. Attempting to build any of these ABIs will result in an error."_

Comment: MIPS and MIPS64 Android-devices have been pretty much non-existent. And Android devices that supported armeabi but not armeabi-v7a stopped being a thing around 2010 or so.

Comment: @Michael is it save to use only  use ` abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"`?

Comment: For the time being, yes. However, starting in August 2019, apps that provide native libraries for 32-bit ABIs (armeabi-v7a, x86) will be required to also provide those libraries for the corresponding 64-bit ABIs (arm64-v8a, x86_64).

Comment: And even though it won't be required until 2019, the 64-bit ABIs usually perform better than their 32-bit counterparts.

Answer (score 8):

As the message says, those ABIs are no longer supported by the NDK. This is mentioned in the [NDK r17 changelog](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/wiki/Changelog-r17):

> Support for ARMv5 (armeabi), MIPS, and MIPS64 has been removed. Attempting to build any of these ABIs will result in an error.

As others have said, there are not a significant number of devices out there that benefit from targeting any of these ABIs.

Answer (score 3):

remove `'armebi`' from `abiFilters` in your `build.gradle` file.
armebi is no longer supported by the NDK. A correct list could be:

```
ndk {
  abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

armeabi are no longer supported by NDK. Remove armeabi from build gradle or replace 
with supported ABIs e.g 'x86'

Answer (score 0):

The same issue using Android Studio 4.1.1 on Windows 10. Changing the version in build.gradle fixes e.g.
from
**classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"**
to
**classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0".**