# ANDROID NDK: Unsupported ABI for NDK r19+: ARMEABI

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-ndk

I have Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1 in Macbook but not able to run app after pulling project from repo. It is giving following error after npx react-native run-android

More Info

Android gradle plugin: 7.1.2

Gradle: 7.4.2

NDK 21.4.7075529

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.
> Unsupported ABI for NDK r19+: ARMEABI
```

Comment: Seems duplicate, see this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52233971/abis-armeabi-mips-are-not-supported-for-platform-android-ndk

Comment: @DanielWynn My build.gradle file doesnt have 
ndk {
  abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
}